# How to read a .mtx file matrix in MATLAB in order to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am currently trying to use MATLAB in order to read a matrix that is a .mtx file and calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. However, I do not have an idea on how to start. The entries for the .mtx matrix file are as follows:

```
    1  1   1.451127632665004e+00 
    1  7   7.249195894283247e-01 
    7  1   7.249195894283247e-01 
    1  13  3.622987922604397e-01 
    13 1   3.622987922604397e-01 
    1  19  7.249195894283247e-01 
    19 1   7.249195894283247e-01 
    1  25  7.249191544766792e-01 
    25 1   7.249191544766792e-01 
    1  31  3.622985748812184e-01 
    ...
```

where the first column represents the line number of the matrix, the second column represents the column number of the matrix, and the third column represents the matrix entry. The matrix size is a 405x405. So I wrote the following code in MATLAB:

```
    fid = fopen('namepath for stiffness matrix'); 
        fid1 = fopen('namepath for mass matrix'); 
    a = fscanf(fid,'%f %f',[2 inf]); 
        a1 = fscanf(fid1,'%f %f',[2 inf]); 
    c1=a(:,1); 
    c2=a(:,2); 
    c3=a(:,3); 
    K=zeros(405,405); 
    fclose(fid); 
    for i=1:405 
       K(c1(i),c2(i))=c3(i); 
       i=i+1; 
    end 
    d1= a1(:,1); 
    d2= a1(:,2); 
    d3= a1(:,3); 
    M=zeros(405,405);
    fclose(fid1);  
    for i=1:405 M(d1(i),
       d2(i))=d3(i); 
       i=i+1; 
    end 
    [phi, w2]=eig(K,M);
```

After running the program, I got the following error:
Index in position 2 is invalid. Array indices must be positive integers or logical values at (line 11)
K(c1(i),c2(i))=c3(i);

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @Hley, welcome to SO. It would be helpful if you are able to provide some examples of what you've tried.

Comment: There is no formatting in comments, so [edit] your question to include the code.